# What does sed -i '1d' do?

Tags: sed

I understand that `sed` is a command to manipulate text file.

From my Googling, it seems `-i` means perform the operation on the file itself, is this correct?

What about `'1d'`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In `sed`:

- `-i` option will edit the input file in-place
- `'1d'` will remove the first line of the input file

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
foo
bar

% sed -i '1d' file.txt 

% cat file.txt        
bar
```

Note that, most of the time it's a good idea to take a backup while using the `-i` option so that you have the original file backed up in case of any unexpected change.

For example, if you do:

```
sed -i.orig '1d' file.txt
```

the original file will be kept as `file.txt.orig` and the modified file will be `file.txt`.

Comment: You can also do a "dry run" without the `-i` to see what happens first, then use `-i` to actually change the file.

Answer (score 18):

### 1. a)

```
sed '1d' file.txt
```

Prints the contents of `file.txt`; *excluding the first line;* to the standard output.

---

### 2. a)

```
sed -i    '1d' file.txt # GNU, NetBSD, OpenBSD
sed -i '' '1d' file.txt # FreeBSD, macOS
```

Prints the contents of `file.txt`; *excluding the first line;* back into `file.txt`; overwriting the original.

---

### 2. b)

```
sed -i.back '1d' file.txt
```

Creates a backup of the original (as `file.txt.back`), before making changes.  Except with FreeBSD `sed`, the suffix (here `.back`) must be attached to the `-i` option (in the same argument, no space between `-i` and `.back`).

---

### 3. a)

```
sed '2d' file.txt
```

Prints the contents of `file.txt`; *excluding the second line;* to the standard output.
(Specifying any number will remove the corresponding line).

Also compatible with the `-i` flag.

---

### 3. b)

```
sed '1!d' file.txt
```

Prints the contents of `file.txt`; *excluding all **but** the first line;* to the standard output.
(In other words; ***only*** the first line gets printed).

Also compatible with the `-i` flag.

---

### 3. c)

```
sed '$d' file.txt
```

Prints the contents of `file.txt`; *excluding the last line;* to the standard output.

Also compatible with the `-i` flag.

Comment: FYI: The BSD version (i.e. macOS de facto standard) typically won't cooperate unless you *create a backup* (2. b), or use the *backup bypass method* (2. c). The GNU version won't prompt you for this. It will destructively edit, and overwrite existing files without hesitation.

Answer (score 5):

In `sed -h` have:

```
  -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
             edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

and 'perform the operation on the file itself.' absolute it'is.

And `man` said: 'Sed  is a stream editor.  A stream editor is used to perform basic text
       transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline).'

as your question,

```
sed -i '1d' file_name
```

means: **delete** the first line in file `"file_name"` at place and backup to file.
(just like edit file and delete first line directly. )